# mLayout.addView() works one time only

Tags: android

I started lately developing for android and got stuck trying to add multiple Views to a Layout. It actually works for the first touch, but after that it does nothing. The Log though keeps working and showing that the touch has been detected and shows the position of the event. I have the following code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private LinearLayout mLayout;
private Context con = this;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lLayout);
    mLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    mLayout.addView(createNewView(event.getX(), event.getY()));
                    Log.d("this ","View has been add." + event.getX()+ ", " + event.getY());
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

private markerView createNewView(float x, float y) {
    final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final markerView mView = new markerView(con, 150, x, y);
    mView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    return mView;
}}
```

and
    public class markerView extends View implements View.OnTouchListener{

```
private Paint paint = new Paint();
private int diameter;
private float X,Y;

public markerView(Context context, int dia, float dx, float dy) {
    super(context);
    diameter = dia;
    X = dx; Y = dy;
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth((float) 4.0);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.drawCircle(X, Y, diameter, paint);
    canvas.restore();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return true;
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just found that the Views ave been created but never show up because the first one has the size of the parentLayout. so i just add the following methode and it worked. the position needs to be changed because of the RelativeLayout but thats not a problem ;)
here is the code:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
   setMeasuredDimension(2*diameter, 2*diameter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try remove `final` tag on your `final markerView mView = new markerView(con, 150, x, y);`